# Can someone identify this brick?

Tags: piece-information, clone-brands

I'm looking for a kind of brick, the brand or the model, which has this specifications: The top has studs. The bottom doesn't have tubes. However, the bottom has support walls in the middle. Here is the picture:

[image]
[image]

What is the brand for this brickset (definitely not LEGO)? Is there a term for this kind of interlocking system?

Comment: How does this compare scale-wise with LEGO? Is that the same dimensions as a 2x4 plate?

Comment: I don't have a LEGO for scale. Here's the measurements: length: 3.75 cm. width: 1.85 cm. height: 1 cm.

Comment: Adding onto Zhaph, how is the quality and compatibility compared to LEGO bricks? Check this pdf for reference:http://uploads.brickset.com/docs/clonebrands_v1.6.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I would say it it cold come from a brand from China, I can’t identify this system, but it is the opposite of that of a normal LEGO brick. It is still a normal 2x4 plate.

Comment: A good clue, but still not enough information to find where to purchase new ones or know whether it's still produced.