# Where to find pictures of undersides of bricks? (possibly Lego clones about 25-30 yrs ago)

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I am trying to identify which non-Lego bricks I might have played in the past. Don't recall the names but I can probably recognize them from photos if I see them again

For example, I remember some 2x4 bricks having two horizontal lines across the center (on the underside).

Comment: Related: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/9880/9417

Comment: @Molot that's pretty close. Is there some proper term to describe the design of the underside that allows blocks to fit together?

Comment: Nothing I know. I just remembered seeing what you described on this site. Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be ***[BRIX BLOX](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=vintage%20BRIX%20BLOX&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR1.TRC0.A0.H0.XBRIX%20BLOX.TRS1&_nkw=BRIX%20BLOX&_sacat=0)***?  Came across these on *eBay* and thought about you...

[image]

[image]

[image]