# I need help identifying vintage knock off blocks

Tags: clone-brands

This may even be two sets. Vintage, without stamp that I can tell. I’m pretty sure some of them have numbers under them. I have included a picture.

[image]

Comment: @ashley_johnson Can you please take another picture showing one block next to a ruler? Right now it's a bit hard to judge the size of the blocks.

Comment: Possibly related to https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9880/can-someone-identify-this-brick

Comment: If you add the picture suggested by @IvanSanchez, please include a close-up of both the top and bottom side of one of the 2x4 bricks. A clear picture of the numbers you mention (or any other markings you can find) might also help.